# Select specific class all values in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have hundred lines of codes. I want to copy all values from class "title". Is there a way to do it?

```
For example :
<span class="_3q9s6"><span dir="auto" title="SAMPLE1" class="ggj6brxn gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 lhj4utae le5p0ye3 l7jjieqr i0jNr">
<span dir="auto" title="SAMPLE2" class="ggj6brxn gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 lhj4utae le5p0ye3 l7jjieqr i0jNr">
<span class="_3q9s6"><span dir="auto" title="SAMPLE3" class="ggj6brxn gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 lhj4utae le5p0ye3 l7jjieqr i0jNr">
```

I want the output of SAMPLE1 , SAMPLE2, and SAMPLE3

Its a HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open find box
2. do a regex search for `(?<=title=")[^"]+`
3. With focus still in find box press `Alt+Enter`
4. `Ctrl+C`
5. `Esc`
6. go to location where you want the texts
7. `Ctrl+V`